# "Have visited here once before" vs "visited here once before"

Tags: grammar

Suppose I have visited France for the second time. Someone welcomes me saying "Hi, welcome to my country. Have you been here before?" Can I reply "thank you. No, this is not the first time I have visited here. I ***have visited/visited here once*** before this visit."

I think both ***have visited*** and ***visited*** work here. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Responding to

> Have you visited here before?

with

> *No*, this is not the first time I have visited here

would be confusing to most people, or at least awkward.

I would respond with either

> Yes, I visited once before.

or

> Yes, this is my second time.

As for whether or not you need the "have", I would probably leave it off, but I think either way is fine.